# Set RowKey property in Windows Azure Table storage to (DateTime now + another property)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there a way in which I can set RowKey to always use Datetime now for my entity that inherits TableEntity class (c#)?

Comment: In the constructor, set the `RowKey` to your preferred string representation of `DateTime.Now` (or better, `DateTime.UtcNow`)

Comment: I want to append another property to my DateTime. But during the constructor call, the other property is not initiated.

Comment: Can this value also be passed in during construction?  BTW, you have just altered the question - you might want to update this so that you include the fact that you are also appending a value.

Comment: Just think in term I want time of insertion to be RowKey rather than the time when object was created. 
The older version of AzureStorage let us write the custom implementation of RowKey but with the introduction of TableEntity, I belive we can't

Comment: Can't you just use the Timestamp property of the entity?  I think some additional details of your use case and what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to set the RowKey property to (DateTime now + another property) manually before inserting. Overriding the RowKey property to always return (DateTime now + another property) is feasible, but it's highly not recommended since it'll make the RowKey property change over time, which is a terrible practice.

Comment: How you can override the RowKey property if it is not set virtual in TableEntity class?

Comment: What about using "new" keyword in RowKey property or directly implementing ITableEntity rather than inherit TableEntity?

Comment: Whenever I am using 'new' keyword - I get 400 Bad request. Can you provide an example of ITableEntity implementation and how to implement ReadEntity and WriteEntity methods ? I tried but I'm unsure about these two methods.